# How to add column header gripper to a custom style of column header in ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, header

So, this is my style. How I can add a gripper to it?
I did not find a way to do it :с

```
<Style x:Key="CustomHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBrushWithLowOpacity}" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited them out yourself my friend.

You can find the default Style and Template here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248(v=vs.110).aspx